How to fill an edge due to overlap and still retain its shape with openCV? Failing to detect a single square contour in a chess board

In this image, the square g1 cannot be detected due to overlapping of g and the board edge. Here is a canny edge image to show what I mean:

Here is the Minimum Reproducible Code after taking a screenshot and detecting the board and resizing the image:
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <vector>
#include <cwchar>
using std::vector;
using namespace cv;
#define ZERO 0
#define MAXVAL 255
static const cv::Size IMG_ANALYSIS_SZ = cv::Size(500, 500);
static const cv::Size STRUCT_KERN_SZ = cv::Size(2, 2);

void show_images(vector<cv::Mat> images) {
    size_t sz = images.size();
    for (size_t count = 0; count < sz; count++) {
        std::string strCnt = std::to_string(count);
        cv::imshow(strCnt, images[count]);
    }
    while (cv::getWindowProperty("0", cv::WND_PROP_VISIBLE) >= 0) {
        int key = cv::waitKey(200);
        if (key == 27) {  // If Esc key is pressed
            break;
        }
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}

static inline double angle(cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2, cv::Point pt0) { // vec A . vec B = |A| |B| cos(theta) 
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}

static inline bool isSquare(double area, double perimeter, vector<cv::Point> contour) {
    double ratio = (16 * area) / (perimeter * perimeter);
    vector<cv::Point> approx;
    approxPolyDP(contour, approx, perimeter*0.02, true);
    if ((ratio > 0.95 && ratio < 1.05) && approx.size() == 4 && isContourConvex(approx)) {
        double maxCos = 0;
        for(size_t i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
            double cos = fabs(angle(approx[i%4], approx[i-2], approx[i-1]));
            if(cos > maxCos) {
                maxCos = cos;
            }
        }
        if(maxCos < 0.3) {  // cos(90) -> 0
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(void) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("0_screenshot.png");
    cv::Mat edge_img;
    cv::Canny(img, edge_img, 0, 255);
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, STRUCT_KERN_SZ);
    dilate(edge_img, edge_img, kernel);
    // I tried the following codes with different configuration and kernels etc.
    //cv::morphologyEx(edge_img, edge_img, cv::MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
    //cv::morphologyEx(edge_img, edge_img, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
    //erode(edge_img, edge_img, kernel);
    vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    cv::findContours(edge_img, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    size_t sz = contours.size();
    vector<vector<cv::Point>> square_contours;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
        double perimeter = cv::arcLength(contours[i], true);
        // why 3200? image size = 500 x 500 and 64 squares on the board
        // (500 x 500) / 64 = 3906.25, So, area of each square little bit less than 3900
        if(isSquare(area, perimeter, contours[i]) && area > 3200 && area < 3910) { 
            square_contours.push_back(contours[i]);
        }    
    }
    printf("%zu", square_contours.size());
    cv::Mat contour_image = cv::Mat::zeros(edge_img.size(), CV_8UC3);
    cv::drawContours(contour_image, square_contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    show_images({ img, contour_image, edge_img });
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


Here is the output image of the contour drawing:

std output:
63

I tried many things, but nothing worked so far. I am failing to detect a single square contour in a chess board which is g1. What can I do to solve this issue?

Unrelated: You copy contour each time you call isSquare. Take it by const& instead. expand_rect doesn't seem to be used so it should be removed from the minimal reproducible example.

@TedLyngmo you mean vector<vector<cv::Point>*> square_contours; and square_contours.push_back(&(contours[i])); but i face problem with cv::drawContours(contour_image, square_contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
`` how to pass the vector square_contours that hold reference?

No, I mean where you currently have static inline bool isSquare(double area, double perimeter, vector<cv::Point> contour). Make the last parameter vector<cv::Point> const& contour

@TedLyngmo Thanks will do that

Also unrelated: You could speed up isSquare quite a lot by returning early if the ratio is outside the limit before calling approxPolyDP. Then, in the loop, you don't need to store maxCos and go through all the angles. Just return false directly when you find a value outside the accepted range. example

Thanks I changed the code similar to your example in my local repo. Good optimizations.

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/failing-to-detect-a-single-contour-of-a-chess-board-square/17443

@ChristophRackwitz In all fairness, the post at that forum does link to this SO post.

I found a very hacky way to solve it. I am not happy about the solution because it uses alot of magic values. The magic values are true for source of my images but does not probably solve the problem as a whole. I just dont know the openCV way of solving it because I am new to openCV.
Here is a function I wrote that finds the edge in a range of y pixel, then removes all possible whites that may cause issues during dilation and fill the edge with whites.
If any one can suggest the openCV way please let me know!
but for now I am using this to complete the board so that I can move chess piece detection:
#define ASSERT_EXIT(expr, str, ...)                                                                                                      \
  ((void) sizeof ((expr) ? 1 : 0), __extension__ ({                                                                                      \
    if (!(expr)) {                                                                                                                       \
        fprintf(stderr,"At function [%s] in file [%s:%d], assert failed: [(%s)].\n" str "\n", __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (#expr));  \
        __VA_ARGS__;                                                                                                                     \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                              \
    }                                                                                                                                    \
  }))
static inline void cure_board_edge_x(int startY, int endY, Mat& img) {
    typedef struct {
        size_t count;
        size_t first_x;
        size_t last_x;
    }RowData;
    size_t len = endY - startY;
    RowData *data = (RowData *)malloc(sizeof(RowData)*(len));
    ASSERT_EXIT(data, "Failed to allocated memory");
    size_t idx = 0;
    size_t max_idx = 0;
    for(int y = startY; y < endY; y++) {
        bool first255found = false;
        for(int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++) {
            if(img.at<uchar>(y, x) == 255) {
                (data[idx].count)++;
                if(!first255found) {
                    first255found = true;
                    data[idx].first_x = x;
                }
                data[idx].last_x = x;
            }
        }
        if(data[idx].count > data[max_idx].count) {
            max_idx = idx;
        } 
        idx++;
    }
    startY = startY + (int)max_idx; //-> location of edge
    int mY = startY - 1;
    int mmY = startY - 2;
    int mmmY = startY - 3;
    int rangeStart = startY - 50;
    int rangeEnd = startY - 30;
    int y;
    for(int x = data[max_idx].first_x + 5; x < data[max_idx].last_x - 5; x++) {
        img.at<uchar>(startY, x) = 255;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            y = rangeStart + (i * (rangeEnd - rangeStart) / 3);
            if (img.at<uchar>(y, x) != 255) {
                img.at<uchar>(mY, x) = img.at<uchar>(mmY, x) = img.at<uchar>(mmmY, x) = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(data);
}

in the main function before dilation add:
int main() {
      // more code above ...............
    if(orientation == WHITE) {
       cure_board_edge_x(490, 495, edge_img);
    }
    dilate(edge_img, edge_img, kernel, cv::Point(-1,-1), 1);
    // more code below ................
}


Suggestion: Replace RowData *data = (RowData *)malloc(sizeof(RowData)*(len)); with auto data = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<RowData[]>(len); to not have to free it manually afterwards. Also, you don't need to typedef your struct RowData. It's type defined automatically in C++. It also seems like you are not initializing your RowDatas before reading from them: (data[idx].count)++ has undefined behavior since you never assigned a value to count before increasing it for example.

Thank you for the great suggestions! The count thing totally slipped my mind.

May I ask. Where did you get all images?

Why is that relevant? I get them from my games I have played over the year online from websites like Lichess and Chess.com. I wrote a program that using webdriver api to automatically changes game and takes screenshot from web browser and then stores them in my computer. After the screen shot it detects the board and crops them to what u see
